# Does FME have spatial "Difference" like QGIS / "Erase" in ArcGIS and Mapinfo?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, fme-form

I am looking for an FME equivalent to the difference/erase tool in QGIS/ArcGIS/Mapinfo. Basically I want to see the spatial change between 2 datasets.

[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76839/distinction-between-difference-and-clip-tools-in-qgis#:~:text=Difference%20creates%20a%20new%20feature,not%20overlap%20the%20%22clipper%22](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76839/distinction-between-difference-and-clip-tools-in-qgis#:%7E:text=Difference%20creates%20a%20new%20feature,not%20overlap%20the%20%22clipper%22).

An old process in FME is https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D54Q000080hcVvSAI/erasing-subtracting-and-merging-polygon-layers

Regards,

Comment: You can find a tutorial on common GIS operations with FME here: https://community.safe.com/s/article/tutorial-common-gis-operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the clipper then connect the outside port to your writer. That should function the same as an Erase in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Clipper transformer to get the areas in the 'clippee' outside of the 'clipper' features.  Or use an AreaOnAreaOverlayer which is like UNION.  It can return all attributes from every input/overlapping polygon.  Then the differences can be queried from the attribute values afterwards.